# 3.x Version has a bug that causes the request body to be sent incorrectly

Tags: okhttp

As shown below, when send the request body, the request header is send as the body content.
[enter image description here][1]

I compared the 3.x and 4.x codes, find two versions on the processing of RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept() is different.

The 4.x version calls the detachWithViolence methods in the finally to release the resource, but the 3.x version does not release the resource if an exception occurs, this results in unsuccessfully send data in the Buffer being consumed by the next request.

Please help to fix this BUG in version 3.x, thank you!

List 135 of class okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor does not execute when an excption is thrown.

Comment: If you think there is an issue with okhttp, you should file a respective bugreport in their [Github project](https://github.com/square/okhttp)

Answer (score -1):

Because the difference between the two version is too big, the team will not upgrade for the time being.
Could you fix the BUG on the 3.x version?

Comment: OkHttp has no plans to backport general issues to specific older versions.  Critical issues would be fixed for 3.12.x (but not 3.14.x) and 4.x.  Most development is on 4.x which is binary compatible with 3.x, so difference to clients is very minimal.

Comment: What are the 4. X and JDK compatible versions?

Comment: 4.9.0 should be used

Comment: I mean, which versions of JDK can 4. X version of okhttp run on?